# configuration file missing error for many packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu:14.04 ROS:indigo
I am using robot_pose_ekf package and am getting this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "controller_manager" with any of the following names:

    controller_managerConfig.cmake
    controller_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "controller_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "controller_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "controller_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed..
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  husky_robot-indigo-devel/husky_base/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

i know the obvious answer would be to install that package but i already tried that then it shows same error with some other name and so on...i compiled the same package on another pc it compiled without any problems and these packages were not there in that pc too......can any one give solution....I tried reinstalling ros and also reinstalling entire ubuntu none worked

PS:not only with robot_pose_ekf i am getting same error with other packages also like husky_base etc.....Hoping for a solution asap Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212078/configuration-file-missing-error-for-many-packages/) by [dheerajgattupalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/22923/dheerajgattupalli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-25**:
Just to get it out of the way: do you *need* to compile from source? *Recommended* pkg installation on Ubuntu is `sudo apt-get install ros-..`, **not** cloning the repository and `catkin_make`-ing. There are situations in which from-source is the only option, but not for normal usage.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-25**:
Also: we don't know what OS, version, version of ROS, etc.

**Comment by [dheerajgattupalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/22923/dheerajgattupalli/) on 2015-06-25**:
i am using ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo i would prefer a general solution and by the way installing sudo apt-get helped with this package thanks......but i need to edit the source code so it would be better if a solution for the error is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> i am using ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo i would prefer a general solution and by the way installing sudo apt-get helped with this package thanks......but i need to edit the source code so it would be better if a solution for the error is available

This is most likely simply a dependency issue: you cannot clone a single package and then expect to be able to build it without also making sure to have all its dependencies present. ROS has a tool for that `rosdep`. See [Installing package from source in Indigo](http://answers.ros.org/question/208963/installing-package-from-source-in-indigo/) for one answer (there are *many* more) that shows how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dheerajgattupalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/22923/dheerajgattupalli/) on 2015-06-25**:
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
this command is giving this error :
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
simplelist: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [Header]
here header is missing config file

**Comment by [dheerajgattupalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/22923/dheerajgattupalli/) on 2015-06-25**:
sir i dont think this is not simple dependency issues i wrote a msg file today with variable header in it and it is showing headercofig is missing......

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-26**:
Did you remember to `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` OR `/path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` (if it exists) before running the `rosdep install ..` command? Please add some info on how you installed ROS: which tutorial did you follow, workspace setup, etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-26**:
Also: copy/paste the contents (add it to your original question) of `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` of the pkg that you wrote that "is showing headercofig is missing.....". Do not include all the boilerplate comments in `CMakeLists.txt` please.

**Comment by [dheerajgattupalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/22923/dheerajgattupalli/) on 2015-06-26**:
thanks for the answer header config was not a package my bad other dependency errors were solved with that command....